# Basic configuration for receiving mails on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

What is the basic configuration needed to receive and store all mails sent to example.com running on an ec2 instance?

i.e. I want to access anything sent to whatever@example.com

**I do not care about sending mails at all**

I am really really new to linux.

Steps completed so far:

MX records set
Port 25 open
Postfix just installed (yum install postfix).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about receiving email on EC2 to anywhere else, you need to point your domains MX record to your server, then you need to make sure you have a mail server running, configured to receive this email. At the very basic level, that is it.

The only EC2 specific thing I can think of is that of IP addresses. You will need to ensure your server has a static (elastic) IP, rather than a dynamic one that could change if the machine is restarted.

Comment: You will also need to open port 25 in the EC2 security group.